# impedir ingresar numero en un input number

Tags: jquery, html5

Buenas, estoy realizando un formulario para ventas. Lo que necesito es saber como puedo impedir que el usuario digite numeros con el teclado dentro de un input number, y que solo pueda incrementar el numero picando a las flechas del propio input.

Este es el codigo:

```js
$(".btn_add").on("click", function() {
  var column1 = $(this).closest('tr').children()[0].textContent;
  var column2 = $(this).closest('tr').children()[1].textContent;
  var column4 = $(this).closest('tr').children()[3].textContent;
  var column5 = $(this).closest('tr').children()[4].textContent;
  
 if($("#second_table .copy_"+column1).length == 0)
  {

    $("#second_table").append("<tr class='copy_"+column1+"'><td>" + column1 + "</td><td>" + column2 + "</td><td>" + column4 + "</td><td>" + column5 + "</td><td><input type='number' class='entrada' min='0'></td><td>--</td><td><button class='btn btn-danger btn_remove'>- Remove</button></td></tr>");
  }
  
});

$("#second_table").on("input", "input", function() {
  var input = $(this);
  var columns = input.closest("tr").children();
  var price = columns.eq(3).text();
  var calculated = input.val() * price;
  columns.eq(5).text(calculated);
  
});

$("body").on("click",".btn_remove", function() {
    $(this).parent().parent().remove();
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- jQuery library -->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<table id="first_table" class="table table-bordered">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th># Code</th>
      <th>Product</th>
      <th>Category</th>
      <th>Stock</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>1</td>
      <td>Monitor A</td>
      <td>X</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>7.5</td>
      <td>
        <button class="btn btn-info btn_add">+ Add</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>2</td>
      <td>Mouse B</td>
      <td>X</td>
      <td>5</td>
      <td>12.4</td>
      <td>
        <button class="btn btn-info btn_add">+ Add</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>3</td>
      <td>Keyboard D</td>
      <td>X</td>
      <td>8</td>
      <td>22.35</td>
      <td>
        <button class="btn btn-info btn_add">+ Add</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>4</td>
      <td>Motherboard C</td>
      <td>Y</td>
      <td>14</td>
      <td>50</td>
      <td>
        <button class="btn btn-info btn_add">+ Add</button>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>

<br>

<table id="second_table" class="table table-bordered table-hover">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th># Code</th>
      <th>Product</th>
      <th>Stock</th>
      <th>Price</th>
      <th>Input</th>
      <th>Calculated Field</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

  </tbody>
</table>

             <div class="form-group col-sm-4">
         <label for="igv">IGV:</label>
           <input type="text" class="form-control"disabled id="igv">
       </div>
       
       <div class="form-group  col-sm-4">
         <label for="total">SubTotal:</label>
           <input type="text" class="form-control" disabled id="total">
       </div>


    <div class="form-group  col-sm-4">
         <label for="totaltotal">Total:</label>
           <input type="text" class="form-control" disabled id="totaltotal">
       </div>
```

Gracias de antemano.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Se me ocurre que podrías usar `keydown()` de esta forma:

```js
$("input").keydown(function() {
  return false
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="number" name="" id="">
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba con la propiedad del input `ReadOnly`. Esta propiedad es similar al `disabled`, con la única salvedad, que los input con la propiedad `disabled` no se envían con el formulario, mientras que los `ReadOnly`,si que se envían como parámetros del formulario.

Comment: ya lo intente pero no funciona, los botones también se desactivan.

Comment: Prueba a crear por un lado el input y por otro los botones de up/down